# How do I stop running scripts in scratch.mit.edu blurring out on Chrome Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, error-handling, mit-scratch

for the last few days, I am encountering an error which is making the code of scratch.mit.edu blur when i click the green flag in chrome. Any fixes?

Comment: "I am encountering an error" If you mean you are seeing an error message, then please copy/paste the complete message text into your question.

Comment: For the past 6 months, there's been plenty of nagging about 'blurry blocks' [on the Scratch forum](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/560413/). I see a slight blur, but that's by design: it's part of the yellow 'glow' to indicate which script(s) are running at any given time. Please state your case by supplying a link to a (shared) project where the problem is visible, together with a screenshot of the blurry content, to guarantee we are both looking at the same thing.

Comment: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/683490316 - is the project link where the error is happening. In the START Sprite

Answer (score 0):

I think the blur you're talking about is the yellow glow from code blocks?

It is **NOT** an error but a feature of scratch. The glow indicates that the code stack/blocks are being executed. Since it appears when you clicked green flag, is the block glowing starts with a `when green flag clicked`? If so it's completely normal don't worry about it.

If this is not the problem please comment to let me know

Comment: ok thanks I understand that it is the glow, but previously when glowing, the block text used to remain clear but now they are blurring

Comment: well that is a scratch bug(or intentional as scratch never said what it is), so you may have to go with it until scratch team fix or change it. Just reminding you it is not a bug of your project